# Disable MapView discrete zoom, change to continuous

Tags: android, zooming, android-mapview

Is it possible to change the discrete zoom in android Mapview to continuous? 
At the moment, if you zoom in with gestures, you actually zoom in steps, as the zoom always bounces back to a certain zoom level.

In iPhone e.g. the zoom level is more continuous, because before loading the new tiles of the next zoom level, it just scales the current tiles, and you can stop zooming anywhere between zoom level n and n+1. Android bounces back to either n or n+1.

Thanks.

EDIT: maybe I can do it manually with scale gestures? Might be a pain though..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to change the discrete zoom in android Mapview to continuous?

No, sorry.

> maybe I can do it manually with scale gestures?

You do not have access to the map tiles.

Comment: But android google application has no descrete zoom. They have implemented own sdk for themself.